# How to embed flash in desktop application in .NET?

Tags: .net

can I embed flash in desktop application in .NET? How?

Comment: I would recommend putting more tags on this question.

Answer (score 3):

This tutorial describes how to do it:

[Embedding a flash player control in a VB.NET winforms application](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic40173.htm)

The key here is to add the "Shockwave Flash Object" COM object to your project.  You'll then have a Shockwave Flash Object control in the toolbox which you can drag onto the form.  Set the Movie property to the .swf object.